# Setting Up angular JS strange error angularjs:12416

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following code academy angularjs initial set up tutorials offline. The reason is so I can use it as a guide for my own app. I have 3 files MainController.js, app.js and index.html.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
  $scope.title = 'Top Sellers in Books'; 
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">



<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
    {{ title }}

</div>

<!-- Modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->

<script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

In the console I am getting this error and I am unable to print the $scope.title

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why it is producing this error

Comment: replace minified angular with non-minified one and you will get to know more details in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `html` code. You have initialized `ng-app` twice, once in `<html>` and once in `<body>` tag. Remove the one in `<html>` tag. Your html code should be as follows,

```
<!doctype html>
<html> <!-- Remove `ng-app` here -->
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"> </script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

        <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
            {{ title }}
        </div>

        <!-- Modules -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This got rid of the error seen in the picture but now I am getting this error 

angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…rs%2FDragon%2FDesktop%2FMAS%2520assignment%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)

Comment: I just tried it out and I'm not able to replicate your error. Are you sure you are not missing anything?

Comment: Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. I get this error, but I swear I am linking everything correctly.

Comment: So is your link to `app.js` file correct? Please check the path.

Comment: Doh! I moved the file and saved it in Sublime text thus creating a duplicate in a different directory! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In `MainController.js` there is no way to know about your app I believe.

You can do this by adding this to the top of the `MainController.js` file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

Note: this is very similar to what's in `app.js` but is different.

```
 // This is the app initialisation, because it includes an array of dependencies
 // as the second argument
 var app = angular.module('myApp', [])


 // This is a way to get your angular app from another file
 var app = angular.module('myApp')
```

Comment: I did what you said , now I am getting this error: angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp... thanks for the help :)

Comment: any chance of you recreating whats there?

Comment: @seus: Your `js` files are perfectly fine. The problem is with your `html`. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code:

1. Your HTML contains two `ng-app` directives, one in `<html>` and one in your `<body>` tag. You need only one `ng-app` directive. So I suggest you remove the one in the `<body>` tag and change `<html ng-app="myApp">`.
2. Your `MainController.js` is in a separate file (module), however you did not define a module object and now it is expecting to have `app` variable in that module. But that will fail to load because `app` is undefined in that module.

You can fix the second problem by defining a module object in `MainController.js`:

```
var Controllers = angular.module('MainControllers', []);

Controllers.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Top Sellers in Books';
}]);
```

You can then inject this controller as a dependency in your `myApp` in `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['MainControllers']);
```

Or you can just move the definition of your `MainController` module from `MainController.js` into `app.js` and use it as it is currently in your code. Like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Top Sellers in Books';
}]);
```

Then remove the line that loads `MainController.js` from your `index.html`.